# Bitbucket error logs when trying to git push

Tags: python, django, git, bitbucket

Trying to push new changes to Bitbucket and suddenly I received this error. The push was successful though.

I was initially confused if the error came from my code since I also used Django, and was paranoid of some weird rare cases that I don't know. But thought at the same time that it's totally different stuff that would not be possible to cross paths.

So I guess there was an error in Bitbucket internally? I was just surprised users are able to see their error logs.

[image]

Comment: @solarissmoke Hi. I'm not sure if I have pipelines since I never configured other things in my repo. I checked the Pipelines in my repo and it's still untouched, still at the setup 'Choose a language template' page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't have pipelienes associated to your BitBucket repository, that might be linked to this [BitBucket incident](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/nsn43vq1lkgj).
It is possible BitBucket is using [PgBouncer (a PostgreSQL connection pooler)](https://twitter.com/agiratech/status/1221995569826140160).

> We are currently investigating an issue cloning repositories over HTTP.
>   Pipelines builds that use HTTP to clone are also impacted.
>
> This incident affected: Git via HTTPS, Mercurial via HTTPS, and Pipelines.

It is resolved though, which means your next push should not trigger any error message.

Comment: Hi, yes actually THAT git push was successful, it just displayed the traceback. So I guess I don't need to file this to Bitbucket then. Thanks.

Comment: @CoderCate Would the *next* git push be successful, *and* generate no error message? In any case, if this is an issue on BitBucket remote side, they are aware indeed.

Comment: The next git actions were successful. However when I tried to deploy on my server and did git pull, that commit I was trying to push that generated a traceback wasn't pulled. I tried to fix it and even did a new clone but it didn't work. So I just committed something new, pulled again and then the missing commit showed up before my last one. I'm not sure if I have to report this but it seems like things are fine now.

Comment: @CoderCate If the issue come up again, a report would be a good idea. The gist of my answer is that the issue probably comes from BitBucket side.